# AlarmManager reset on reboot

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager

I've an alarm which opens an activity at a time chosen by the user. If the user hits the start button, the alarm goes fine but it gets cancelled after reboot. I've looked everywhere and it says that I should use a service. Is it possible to keep the alarms on after the reboot without using service? I'm new to coding so can you please breakdown what I need to do. Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button disable;
Button start;
TimePicker timePicker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    disable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disable_alarm);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),notification.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 120*1000, pendingIntent);

        }
    });

    disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),notification.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    });
```

and Broadcast Receiver is

```
public class notification extends BroadcastReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, pop_up2.class);
    scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);}}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for when the system boots up and from there you need to reset your `AlarmManager` events.

Comment: If it reset them, the alarm will go off regardless the user wants it to go or not. I only want the alarm to go if the user wants it to go.

Comment: Yeah, I usually keep my alarms in a `SharedPreference` and remove them from there as soon as they go off. So, in your `receiver` you simply schedule all the alarms that are there in your preferences. This of course is dependent on your use case.

Comment: You create a boolean for your alarm on and alarm off events? I thought of doing that but I thought it might be buggy.

Comment: I don't see how it can be buggy since we can read/write `SharedPreference` in UI thread only. I haven't found any issues with it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the active alarms are cancelled after phone is shutdown. In order to reset the alarms you need to use a separate **broadcast receiver** that will receive only boot completed action. The receiver then starts **service** that will reset all your alarms in background. Best one for you is `IntentService`, because it ends itself when the work is done. Of course you need to store the information about alarms somewhere in order to remember which ones to reset. You can use, for example, SQLite to store them.

In your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name="developer.marat.apps.days.Alarms.BootCompletedReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name="developer.marat.apps.days.Alarms.RestartAlarmsService"/>
```

Special receiver:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, RestartAlarmsService.class);
            ComponentName service = context.startService(i);
        }
    }
}
```

RestartAlarms:

```
public class RestartAlarmsService extends IntentService{

    public RestartAlarmsService() {
        super("RestartAlarmsService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Restart your alarms here.
        // open database, iterate through every alarm and set them again

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the service start regardless of user asking the alarm to go?

Comment: Service starts only one time after reboot. It works on its own. You need to write code so that the service checks all the registered alarms from db. There you need to store only active alarms. If the user cancels particular alarm, you need to delete it from db or mark it as inactive. So, your service resets only necessary alarms.

Comment: I'm new to coding. I've no idea how to do that. Sorry

Comment: First of all, you need to create database. It can be SQLite, or Shared preferences. When user presses button to set some alarm, the code inside of `setOnClickListener` is worked out and alarm is set. Just include code that will store alarm in db after setting alarm. Then simply read it in your IntentService. There are many tutorials on how to create and work with db. Search them and you will understand it. It's easy, don't worry

Comment: Similarly to the storing alarm information in db when it gets set, you need to include code that deletes the information about the alarm that is cancelled by user. Similar code needs to be included inside of `onClickListener` of `disable` button. And thats all!

Comment: I know how to use shared preference with booleans. If the start button sends a boolean which triggers the alarm and the cancel button sends a boolean which cancels the alarm, would that work? If that works, would a boot broadcast still be needed?

Comment: Shared preference is used only to store the information about alarm. It does not set or reset or any other manipulation with alarms. It is like a notepad that is used to keep information. In order to reset alarms in must use boot completed receiver that starts service which resets alarms.

Comment: So I'll have to use SharedPreference with .putExtra for start and stop buttons so when service starts, it can find out if alarm should go off or not?

Comment: You are partially right. Service start only and only after phone was rebooted. At that moment no alarms are active. All of them are cancelled when phone was turned off. So, when service starts it reads information from shared preferences and finds out which alarms need to be reactivated/reset again.

Comment: I'll start the alarm on start button but also pass data to shared preference so service can read it upon reboot. Thanks for your help brother. God bless you.

Comment: Glad to know that I could help. I will appreciate if you accept and upvote my answer. And please approve my edit) Happy coding

Comment: @Marat Broadcast receiver is called after reboot . But Service is not calling. I checked it by putting a log statement in onHandleIntent method.

Comment: @Marat IntentService and JobIntentService now deprecated.  Any ideas on how best to reset a large number of future alarms in the background?

Comment: I needed to add
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
in the intent-filter in the manifest to make this work on OnePlus 8T (Android 11).